# Return instance of class from base class

Tags: php, laravel, class

I'd like to create an object like so:

```
class Obj extends BaseModel {

    public function doSomething() {
        // do some stuff with the instance
    }
}



class BaseModel {

    public static function find($id){
        // retrieve object from database and return instance of Obj class
    }
}
```

So i can achieve the following:

```
$obj1 = Obj::find(1);
$obj1->doSomething();
```

How can I create this so that the static method from the base class returns an instance of the Obj class?

(similar to how Laravel handles objects)

Comment: Make a query to db or use ORM, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your base model, you can get the class of the children that's been called with [get_called_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php).

```
class Obj extends Base{

    private $id;

    public function __construct($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $id;
    }

}

class Base{

    public static function find($id){
        $class = get_called_class();
        return new $class($id);
    }

}
```

### Example

```
$obj = Obj::find(1);
```

### var_dump of $obj

```
object(Obj)#1 (1) {
  ["id":"Obj":private]=>
  int(1)
}
```